# Stored procedure for copying data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am all new to creating procedures and triggers in MySQL, but have struggled with this over the last couple of days, and it simply will not work. The error messages, that I get from Mysql does not help me any longer.

So I am trying to create a procedure, which I need to run after an update. I will take any updates and store new data in a dynamic created table in another database.
Here it is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_price_storage_table (IN market_id INT(11), OUT tablename VARCHAR(50))
            BEGIN
                SET @NUMBER     = CEILING(market_id / 100000) * 100000;
                SET tablename   = CONCAT('price_',@NUMBER);
                SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.',tablename,'(
                                    `pk_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                    `fk_market_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                                    `fk_outcome_type_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                                    `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
                                    `status` ENUM(\'enabled\',\'disabled\') NOT NULL,
                                    `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
                                    PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`)
                                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8')');
                PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
            END;
```

This need to be triggered after update, where the SQL goes like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER copy_price_data AFTER UPDATE ON price
        FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
                IF NEW.updated <> OLD.updated THEN
                    SET @market_id = NEW.fk_market_id;
                    SET @tablename = NULL;
                    CALL create_price_storage_table(@market_id, @tablename);
                    SELECT @tablename;
                    SET @SQL = CONCAT(
                    'INSERT INTO ',
                    @tablename,
                    ' (`fk_market_id`, `fk_outcome_type_id`, `price`, `status`, `created`) VALUES (NEW.fk_market_id, NEW.fk_outcome_type_id, NEW.price, NEW.status, NOW())');
                    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
                    EXECUTE stmt;
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
                END IF;
            END;
```

When trying to create the procedure, then I get the following error message from MySQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_price_storage_table (IN market_id INT(11), OUT tablename VARCHAR(50))
        BEGIN
            SET @NUMBER     = CEILING(market_id / 100000) * 100000;
```

> MySQL returnerede: Dokumentation 1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

I hope someone with greater understanding than me, can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE get_price_storage_table (IN market_id INT(11), OUT tablename VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @NUMBER     = CEILING(market_id / 100000) * 100000;
    SET tablename   = CONCAT('price_',@NUMBER);
    SET @SQL = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data.',tablename,'(
                        `pk_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `fk_market_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                        `fk_outcome_type_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                        `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
                        `status` ENUM(\'enabled\',\'disabled\') NOT NULL,
                        `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`)
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;
```

By:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `get_price_storage_table`(`market_id` INT UNSIGNED, OUT `tablename` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    DECLARE `NUMBER` INT UNSIGNED;
    SET `NUMBER`     := CEILING(`market_id` / 100000) * 100000;
    SET `tablename`  := CONCAT('`price_', NUMBER, '`');
    SET @`SQL`       := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', tablename, '(
                        `pk_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        `fk_market_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                        `fk_outcome_type_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
                        `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
                        `status` ENUM(\'enabled\',\'disabled\') NOT NULL,
                        `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`)
                        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8');
                     -- ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8')');
    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`SQL`;
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//
```

Example:

```sql
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_price_storage_table`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `get_price_storage_table`(`market_id` INT UNSIGNED, OUT `tablename` VARCHAR(50))
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE `NUMBER` INT UNSIGNED;
    ->     SET `NUMBER`     := CEILING(`market_id` / 100000) * 100000;
    ->     SET `tablename`  := CONCAT('`price_', NUMBER, '`');
    ->     SET @`SQL`       := CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ', tablename, '(
     >                         `pk_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     >                         `fk_market_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     >                         `fk_outcome_type_id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
     >                         `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
     >                         `status` ENUM(\'enabled\',\'disabled\') NOT NULL,
     >                         `created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
     >                         PRIMARY KEY (`pk_id`)
     >                         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8');
    ->     PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`SQL`;
    ->     EXECUTE `stmt`;
    ->     DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `get_price_storage_table`(1, @`tablename`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @`tablename`;
+----------------+
| @`tablename`   |
+----------------+
| `price_100000` |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_test |
+----------------+
| price_100000   |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errors are to be located to the left (or above) of the place reported in the error message, since the reported place is the first thing that confuses MySQL.
In your case this is the `;`
It finishes your `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement, but MySQL expects more to come, like an `END`. 
Procedures / Triggers / Functions have to be declared with a different delimiter when they consist of more than one statement.

Try like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE whatever()
BEGIN
SELECT 'whatever';
SELECT 'another';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```